# How to generate realistic packet jitter values in a simulation?

Tags: networking, internet, p2p, simulation, jitter

I am currently simulating a peer-to-peer overlay focused on video streaming over HTTP. When a peer wants to send an HTTP message to another peer, the delay is calculated.

Currently I am calculating delay as: delay = transmission delay + propagation delay

where transmission delay = message size / transmission rate

and propagation delay = distance / propagation speed

Now, apart from transmission and propagation delay, I would also like to consider packet jitter such that: total delay = transmission delay + propagation delay + jitter

I am stuck at finding a realistic way to generate jitter values. I was trying to find a way such that I can use the details of transmission and propagation delay to approximate a jitter value.

I have found that packet jitter can be approximated using a log-normal distribution however I'm not sure which mean and standard deviation values to use. 
I also found that the interquartile range of jitter values is usually in the range of 0 to 20 ms based on measurement data.

Therefore I was thinking of using log-normal distribution with a mean of 1 and standard deviation of 1 to generate values in the range of 0-20ms. However I have invented the values of mean and standard deviation so I don't think that's the correct way of generating realistic jitter.
Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: It seems like any good answer to your question would require empirical measurement and quantitative characterization of jitter in real-world Internet applications, and I'm not sure you'll find anyone here that can speak to that authoritatively. This feels like something you should be searching the academic literature for.

Comment: I didn't have high hopes when posting this question for the reasons you mentioned. I did search academic literature mate but unfortunately information is really scarce about modeling jitter and I listed the only reliable information I found in the question. I just decided to try and ask here as a last resort maybe somebody would have done something similar in the past.